# How to remove all controls except one?

Tags: c#, winforms

If I want to remove all the GroupBox controls, I can use:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToList())
{
    this.Controls.Remove(c);
}
```

**How can I have an exception here?** In other words, I would like to delete all the GroupBox controls except where the name of the GroupBox is "Groupbox1".

Comment: `var controlsToRemove = Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToList().Where(ctrl => ctrl.Name != "Groupbox1")`

Comment: I think the OP wants a solution where he can delete all controls on a form except for those that belong to Groupbox1.

Comment: well Rufus's suggestion will still work because OP doesn't take controls recursively. if you don't remove GroupBox you won't remove any of it's child controls either.

Comment: I wonder why all the downvotes! It's a legit _understandable_ question from a beginner who clearly doesn't have a perfect English. IMO, an edit is better than a downvote here.

Comment: `if(c!=groupBox1)`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to Rufus's solution if you know the names of the GroupBoxes that you want to exclude *beforehand*, you can use the [`Enumerable.Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) method:

```
foreach (var grp in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().
                        Except(new[] { groupBox1, groupBox7 }).ToList())
{
    Controls.Remove(grp);
}
```

[image: Delete GroupBoxes]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter to your query to exclude the name of the control you don't want to delete:

```
foreach (var groupBoxToDelete in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToList()
    .Where(ctrl => ctrl.Name != "groupBox1"))
{
    Controls.Remove(groupBoxToDelete);
}
```